# Local notifications don't fire at new time when rescheduled Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

In my app I'm using `flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.2` plugin for local notifications.
User selects which weekdays to schedule an `alarm` and when saving I pass the `alarm` object to the `setSchedulerNotifications` method to set a notification for each day in the alarm's `repeatWeekdays` list.
I loop through the `repeatWeekdays` list and set a notification at each loop, with an id that is the passed in alarm id + the loop number, to be incremental.
So far everything works as expected.

Now, when alarm gets edited ( different time ), on saving I pass the new alarm to `modifySchedulerNotification` method which first calls `deleteSchedulerNotifications` method (which has the same loop to calculate notification id), and then calls `setSchedulerNotifications` again.

Prints show that notification ids in `setSchedulerNotifications` are correct and they are consistent in `deleteSchedulerNotifications` and second `setSchedulerNotifications` call but when set the second time (same ids as the first time) notifications don't fire at the the new time, but the fire at the old time.

Can you spot what am I doing wrong?

## Notification methods:

## Set

```
Future<void> setSchedulerNotifications(Alarm alarm) async {
    print(
        '##### LocalNotificationRepository().setSchedulerNotifications called');
    print('##### sound to play is : ${alarm.sound.toLowerCase()}');
    for (int i = 0; i < alarm.repeatWeekdays.length; i++) {
      List<String> repeat = alarm.repeatWeekdays;
      int notificationId = int.parse(alarm.alarmId) + i;
      print('##### Scheduling local notification with id: $notificationId,\n'
          '###### for alarm with id ${alarm.alarmId}\n'
          '##### i = $i');
      String notificationChannelId = 'checkRoute_${alarm.sound}';
      String notificationChannelName = 'checkRoute_${alarm.alarmName}';
      String notificationChannelDescription =
          'Scherduled checking for route ${alarm.alarmName}';
      String sound = alarm.sound.toLowerCase();
      DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat('HH:mm');
      var date = dateFormat.parse(alarm.time);
      int hour = date.hour;
      int minute = date.minute;
      Time time = Time(hour, minute, 0);

      var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
          notificationChannelId, //'show weekly channel id',
          notificationChannelName, //'show weekly channel name',
          notificationChannelDescription, //'show weekly channel description');
          priority: Priority.High,
          sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('$sound'));
      var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails(
          presentAlert: true, presentSound: true, presentBadge: true);
      var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
          androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .showWeeklyAtDayAndTime(
              notificationId,
              sprintf(
                  AppLocalizations.instance
                      .text('ROUTE_CHECK_NOTIFICATION_TITLE'),
                  [alarm.alarmName]), //'show weekly title',
              AppLocalizations.instance.text(
                  'ROUTE_CHECK_NOTIFICATION_BODY'), //'show weekly subtitle',
              selectDay(repeat[i]),
              time,
              platformChannelSpecifics,
//          categoryIdentifier: "ROUTE_CHECK_CATEGORY",
              payload: alarm.routeName)
          .whenComplete(() {
        print('##### Scheduled local notification with id: $notificationId');
      });
    }
    print('##### LocalNotificationRepository().setWeeklyNotifications()\n'
        '##### all notifications for this route check are set');
  }
```

## Delete

```
  Future<void> deleteSchedulerNotifications(Alarm alarm) async {
    print(
        '@@@@ LocalNotificationRepository().deleteSchedulerNotifications called');

    for (int i = 0; i < alarm.repeatWeekdays.length; i++) {
      int id = int.parse(alarm.alarmId) + i;
      print('@@@@ Deleting local notification with id: $id,\n'
          '###### for alarm with id ${alarm.alarmId}\n'
          '##### i = $i');
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(id).catchError((e) {
        print(
            '@@@@ LocalNotificationRepository().deleteSchedulerNotifications error: $e');
      }).whenComplete(() {
        print('@@@@ Deleted local notification with id: $id');
        print('@@ LocalNotificationRepository().deleteWeeklyNotifications()\n'
            '@@ all notifications for this route check are deleted');
//        return;
      });
    }
  }
```

## Modify

```
  Future<void> modifySchedulerNotification(Alarm alarm) async {
    print(
        '## LocalNotificationRepository().modifyWeeklyNotifications() called\n'
        '## for alarm ${alarm.toMap().toString()}');
    await deleteSchedulerNotifications(alarm).whenComplete(() async {
      print('## LocalNotificationRepository().modifyWeeklyNotifications()\n'
          '## old notifications for alarm ${alarm.toMap().toString()} have been deleted.\n'
          '## are there new notifications to be set? ${alarm.enabled}');
      if (alarm.enabled == true) {
        await setSchedulerNotifications(alarm).whenComplete(() {
          print('## LocalNotificationRepository().modifyWeeklyNotifications()\n'
              '## new notifications for alarm ${alarm.toMap().toString()} are set');
          return;
        });
      }
    });

    print(
        'modifyWeeklyNotifications() all notifications for this route check are modified');
  }
```

## Prints:

## First save

```
I/flutter ( 1520): SetNotification received
I/flutter ( 1520): SchedulerRepository().saveAlarm() calledfor alarm: {alarmId: 815816479, alarmName: test, enabled: true, repeatWeekdays: ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"], time: 21:05, sound: fixitTheme, routeName: test}
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### LocalNotificationRepository().setSchedulerNotifications called
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### sound to play is : fixittheme
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduling local notification with id: 815816479,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 0
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduled local notification with id: 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduling local notification with id: 815816480,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 1
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduled local notification with id: 815816480
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduling local notification with id: 815816481,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 2
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduled local notification with id: 815816481
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduling local notification with id: 815816482,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 3
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduled local notification with id: 815816482
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduling local notification with id: 815816483,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 4
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduled local notification with id: 815816483
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### LocalNotificationRepository().setWeeklyNotifications()
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### all notifications for this route check are set
```

## Modify save

```
I/flutter ( 1520): ModifyNotification received
I/flutter ( 1520): SchedulerRepository().saveAlarm() calledfor alarm: {alarmId: 815816479, alarmName: test, enabled: true, repeatWeekdays: ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"], time: 21:07, sound: fixitTheme, routeName: test}
I/flutter ( 1520): ## LocalNotificationRepository().modifyWeeklyNotifications() called
I/flutter ( 1520): ## for alarm {alarmId: 815816479, alarmName: test, enabled: true, repeatWeekdays: ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"], time: 21:05, sound: fixitTheme, routeName: test}
I/flutter ( 1520): @@@@ LocalNotificationRepository().deleteSchedulerNotifications called
I/flutter ( 1520): @@@@ Deleting local notification with id: 815816479,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 0
I/flutter ( 1520): @@@@ Deleted local notification with id: 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): @@ LocalNotificationRepository().deleteWeeklyNotifications()
I/flutter ( 1520): @@ all notifications for this route check are deleted
I/flutter ( 1520): @@@@ Deleting local notification with id: 815816480,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 1
I/flutter ( 1520): @@@@ Deleted local notification with id: 815816480
I/flutter ( 1520): @@ LocalNotificationRepository().deleteWeeklyNotifications()
I/flutter ( 1520): @@ all notifications for this route check are deleted
I/flutter ( 1520): @@@@ Deleting local notification with id: 815816481,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 2
I/flutter ( 1520): @@@@ Deleted local notification with id: 815816481
I/flutter ( 1520): @@ LocalNotificationRepository().deleteWeeklyNotifications()
I/flutter ( 1520): @@ all notifications for this route check are deleted
I/flutter ( 1520): @@@@ Deleting local notification with id: 815816482,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 3
I/flutter ( 1520): @@@@ Deleted local notification with id: 815816482
I/flutter ( 1520): @@ LocalNotificationRepository().deleteWeeklyNotifications()
I/flutter ( 1520): @@ all notifications for this route check are deleted
I/flutter ( 1520): @@@@ Deleting local notification with id: 815816483,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 4
I/flutter ( 1520): @@@@ Deleted local notification with id: 815816483
I/flutter ( 1520): @@ LocalNotificationRepository().deleteWeeklyNotifications()
I/flutter ( 1520): @@ all notifications for this route check are deleted
I/flutter ( 1520): ## LocalNotificationRepository().modifyWeeklyNotifications()
I/flutter ( 1520): ## old notifications for alarm {alarmId: 815816479, alarmName: test, enabled: true, repeatWeekdays: ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"], time: 21:05, sound: fixitTheme, routeName: test} have been deleted.
I/flutter ( 1520): ## are there new notifications to be set? true
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### LocalNotificationRepository().setSchedulerNotifications called
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### sound to play is : fixittheme
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduling local notification with id: 815816479,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 0
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduled local notification with id: 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduling local notification with id: 815816480,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 1
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduled local notification with id: 815816480
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduling local notification with id: 815816481,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 2
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduled local notification with id: 815816481
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduling local notification with id: 815816482,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 3
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduled local notification with id: 815816482
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduling local notification with id: 815816483,
I/flutter ( 1520): ###### for alarm with id 815816479
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### i = 4
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### Scheduled local notification with id: 815816483
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### LocalNotificationRepository().setWeeklyNotifications()
I/flutter ( 1520): ##### all notifications for this route check are set
I/flutter ( 1520): ## LocalNotificationRepository().modifyWeeklyNotifications()
I/flutter ( 1520): ## new notifications for alarm {alarmId: 815816479, alarmName: test, enabled: true, repeatWeekdays: ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"], time: 21:05, sound: fixitTheme, routeName: test} are set
I/flutter ( 1520): modifyWeeklyNotifications() all notifications for this route check are modified
I/flutter ( 1520): LocalNotificationBLoc._modifySchedulerNotification() notifications have been modified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the bug.. I was passing the old `Alarm` object to `modifySchedulerNotification` method.